# ACRA prevents stacktraces print in logcat

Tags: android, acra

I have a basic ACRA config setup to email my crash reports, which is working fine. However, it is now preventing the stacktrace from print in logcat (both command line and Android Studio, with all filters turned off).

My config:

```
@ReportsCrashes(formKey = "",
             mailTo = "XXXX",
             mode = ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST,
             resToastText = R.string.crash)
public class ApplicationController extends Application {
...
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
 ACRA.init(this);

}
}
```

EDIT

I am using

compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.5.0'

and logcat prints

ACRA caught a InternalError exception for com.example.staging. Building report.

when I do a simple throw NullPointerException. I get the full stack track if I don't init ACRA

Comment: Post your logcat showing what you see. Post the code you are using to test Exception handling. What version of ACRA are you using?

Comment: Post your **full** logcat within a code window. NB you are using an old version of ACRA - 4.6.2 is the latest. And you haven't specified a formUri

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. have you found a solution ?

Comment: @miladzahedi no, ended up using Bugsnag

Comment: @recipherus I used a simple if to check that the build is in debug mode and init acra if it is not, pretty simple solution !

Answer (score 0):

ACRA doesn't prevent stacktraces being printed in logcat. It is not possible for it do so.